# How to access arrays from multiple different forms?

Tags: c#, winforms

Currently creating a project which requires me to declare a public array in the program class and then access and add to this array in one of my forms. When I declare the array in the program class, it says that it does not exist when I try to reference it in a different form.

How can I make the array accessible from all of my forms?

Comment: I advise you to separate data from GUI and use the MVC (Model view controller) pattern, take a look here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller.
In the MVC pattern your form is the view, your data is the model, the controller performs the data access an manipulation.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Declare it as a static variable in the `Program` class, something like:

```
public static string[] MyArr = {"my", "array"};
```

Then whenever you want to access it, use `Program.MyArr`.